# What does "as" keyword mean in Laravel routing?

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

As I understand from the Laravel documentation, it's used for redirection, but maybe I'm wrong.

I wrote

```php
Route::get('user/profile', ['as' => 'profile', function () {
    echo 'some_text';
}]);
```

then I was expecting my URL to redirect from
`https://base_url/public/index.php/user/profile` to `https://base_url/public/index.php/profile` but it doesn't happen.

Overall, I want to know, what the difference is if I used

```php
Route::get('user/profile', function () {
    echo 'some_text';
});
```

instead of the above routing rule.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The purpose isn't for re-direction in your routing file.

Instead, with the example route you provided, Laravel will allow you to reference said route by using:

```
$url = route('profile');
```

So you don't have to build the URL manually over and over again in your code.

So, in short: the difference is the first thing is a named route, and the last thing is a non-named route. Since you called the first route, you can reference it by that name.

Comment: where is the `as` keyword documented in the Laravel doc ?

Comment: As keyword is in older version, if you change the documentation to 5.2 you can see the `as` keyword. In newer version it's `->name`

Comment: So it's like the `name()` method, right ?

Comment: @EyadMohammedOsama Yes, it is the same.