# unit testing for Controller's index function

Tags: laravel

This is my function :

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $data = User::all();
    return view('data.index',[
        'data' => $data
    ]);
}
```

I write a test for this

```
public function testIndex()
{
   $response = $this->call('GET', '/data');

   $this->assertEquals(200, $response->status());
}
```

but not works. Show redirection

```
Response status code [302] is not a successful status code.
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

Here is my route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'data'], function() {
    Route::get('/', ['as' => 'data.index', 'uses' => 'DataController@index']);
});
```

I tried everything but still showing the same thing.

Comment: which larvel version you are using , also what's your route file name is ?

Comment: laravel 5.7 and route file name is web.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "as" keyword really mean in Laravel routing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30860914/what-does-as-keyword-really-mean-in-laravel-routing)

Comment: check this one https://laravel.io/forum/03-07-2014-testcase-tests-unable-to-make-multiple-call

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your `index()` method as following :

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $data = User::all();
    return view('data.index',[
        'data' => $data
    ])->setStatusCode(200);
}
```

Hope it will helps you. Thanks